# AEM DAM image replace - references in pages not updating

Tags: adobe, aem

I have a problem with references to an image not updating in pages that are using that image.

This is the steps that the users are reporting

1. go to **/siteadmin#/content/dam/**
2. on the "new" dropdown menu, select "new file"
3. select an image file that is a different image but has the same name as a file that already exists
4. upload the file and when asked that a file already exists, choose replace
5. activate the file when the upload completes

The problem is that when I check pub I can see the image is updated, and if I navigate to the path of the image, for example:

**pub1.mypub:4503/content/dam//my-image.png**

I can see the new image I replaced the old one with

the problem is that pages that were referencing the image, specifically the image component, still shows the old image. I've check flush rules, checked workflows and nothing seems to work

The one thing I noticed is that in pages that are referencing the image the path is like this

**/content//_jcr_content/my-component/my-component-parsys/columns/parsyscenter/image.img.jpg/1538602163986.jpg**

so it seems the path it is using is like a generated path and not the same path as this one: **pub1.mypub:4503/content/dam//my-image.png**

im at a complete loss, I honestly do not know what else to check, has anyone ran into this and figured out how to fix it?

this is on aem 6.3

the problem is that in pubs the image being referenced in the component does not update, and since it does not update in pub, it never updates dispatcher

Comment: as a quick fix you can re-activate/clear cache for all the pages that are referencing the image. assuming your publisher is behind a dispatcher.it will work.

Comment: however replacing the image is not a good idea, AEM generates expire header for the image that can cause it to be cached in browser, cdn, proxies etc. you should upload the new asset with a new name and update the pages wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try activating the referenced pages after the image has been published. Since the page on publish has reference to the previous image.

Comment: that would work, except the image is a logo that is in use in multiple pages and activating them one by one wont work, also the content authors dont want to do a mass reactivation, they want to replace the image in the DAM, activate the image and then see it updated everywhere

Comment: Not sure if that is possible because the image reference will be updated only when the page is reactivated. 
As an alternative, you could have some pre-check condition to compare if the page has been modified post it's last publish. If yes, do not activate the page else activate it.

Comment: However, it would not work for a logo as some pages might have the previous logo while the others might have been updated. 
You could modify the condition to satisfy your use case. If all the referenced pages  of the image have not been modified after its last publish only then activate the page.